# HCatalog notifications on HDInsight

Tags: hadoop, hive, activemq-classic, azure-hdinsight, hcatalog

I am trying to enable HCatalog notifications on an HDInsight cluster so that I can keep track of the metadata changes.

I have an ActiveMQ broker running on both of my headnodes. It is working as I have been able to subscribe to it and receive notifications that I was sending to myself. I tried enabling the HCatalog notifications by changing the configuration of the hive-site.xml through the Ambari UI (I added *org.apache.hive.hcatalog.listener.NotificationListener* in the *hive.metastore.event.listeners* field) but that didn't give any results. I also connected to the headnode of my HDInsight cluster via SSH and manually changed the configuration in hive-site.xml files (there are apparently quite a few of these) by adding a property like I tried through Ambari and event that didn't work. After every configuration change I restarted hive (and even all) services through the Ambari UI. My guess is that, for some reason, the changes that I made are not being applied.

Any experience or advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to activate a custom notification listener by doing the following:

1. Package the class which implements the **MetaStoreEventListener** interface into a jar
2. Place the jar into the lib folder of hive-server on every headnode
3. In the Ambari UI, go to *`Hive => Configs => Advanced => Custom hive-site`* and add the property:

   `hive.metastore.event.listeners=[full_class_name_including_package]`
4. Save the configuration (if warnings occur, click Proceed Anyway)
5. Restart all affected services when prompted.

After going through these steps the metastore called my notification listener after every `DDL` operation and I was able to keep track of all the metadata changes.